# Unable to do debugging in cucumber in intellij idea

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, cucumber

I tried to debug my personal project which is in cucumber framework. Debugging seems run properly till one gherkin key word like eg:I am debugging WHEN it's debugging properly till the last line but I tried to step over its going into some other java library class.please take a look on the below screen shot of it. 
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you step *into* the method in your debugger, it will go into any Java or Cucumber class you are using, so you can see exactly what happens / what code is getting called.

Instead, try stepping *over* the method to get just the result of the method call and to stay in "your" code, or setting multiple breakpoints in your code (you can run the debugger from breakpoint to breakpoint and check the state in each point).